# How does the closure operate in returning function when using circulating variables?

Tags: python, closures

```
def count():
    fs = []
    for i in range(1, 4):
        def f():
             return i*i
        fs.append(f)
    return fs


f1, f2, f3 = count()
print(f1(), f2(), f3())
```

I'm learning Python, finding the result above is `9 9 9` instead of `1 4 9`. I try to debug the code step by step, but in IDE I cannot get any extra information about `<function count.<locals>.f at 0x0000000003987598>` when appending functions to list. I wanna know what is the detail order of the code, especially when appending `f()` whether the value of the variable `i` would be recorded(i*i or 1*1 or some other circumstance). And what 's the significance of `for i in range(1, 4)`?

Comment: The inner `f` function gets a reference to `i`. So all your `f` use the same `i`, with whatever value it has at the time you call the `f`s

Comment: It is quite simple: the closure captures the *variable* `i` itself, not the value at the given moment. This is an example of "late-binding" closures. So think about it: what is the value of `i` when the for-loop is over, i.e. *when your list of functions returns*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok, this answer is explicit, thx

Comment: IOW, you've created 3 functions all that have a closure over the *same variable `i`*, and they do the exact same thing with that variable, so of course, they return the same value! Anyway, check out the linked duplicates above for more details.